# naming txt output files python

Tags: python, input, text-files, output, rename

I am trying to get .txt output files from Python, but I have serious problems with overwriting my .txt file every time I run the program (the output .txt file always has the same name). Now I have this commands:

```
with open("outputHorizontal.txt", 'w') as file:
    for item in I_list:
           file.write("{}\n".format(item))
```

With this code I get a txt file with all the I_list data, but if I run the program several times, I can only see the last txt file (the other ones has been overwritten and deleted).

I am really interested in knowing how to automatically rename this output .txt file (now called 'outputHorizontal.txt'), in order to have data from every time I run the program. Is there any way to make the name change according to the input that the user has to enter in the program to run it? For example, the latitude (as 'lat) is a input of the program, and would be nice to make the txt file name could be changed automatically according to 'lat' (every time 'lat' changes, the txt file names also changes).

And, which is the best way to extract data from Python, using .txt files or .csv files? Thanks you in advance people. Kind regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameterize the file name, like you suggested:

```
with open("outputHorizontal.{0}.txt".format(lat), 'w') as file:
    for item in I_list:
        file.write("{}\n".format(item))
```

Comment: Oh, that's perfect! I get every time different .txt files, according to the value of 'lat'. So thankful!

Answer (score 0):

To append to existing file, the opening mode should be 'a', instead of 'w':

```
with open("{}.txt".format(filename), 'a') as file:
    for item in I_list:
        file.write("{}\n".format(item))
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but I am more interested in get different .txt files (all of them with the name according to the value of latitude ('lat') that the user inputs to Python). In this way, I want to store all these .txt files, in order to be able of compare their data in the future. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best option would be the mode `a+`, as it states in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open):

> Modes `'r+'`, `'w+'` and `'a+'` open the file for updating (note that 'w+' truncates the file).

So:

```
with open("outputHorizontal.txt", 'a+') as file:
    for item in I_list:
        file.write("{0}\n".format(item))
```

This will append the data to the file. However, if you simple want a name change each time, then:

```
with open("...{0}.txt".format(your_variable), 'a+'):
```

Answer (score 0):

Just parameterize the filename:

```
with open("%s.txt"%lat, 'w') as f:
```

This will work fine.

If you want to have `output1.txt, output2.txt, output3.txt`, i have a nice way to do it.

```
i = 0
while i: #keep trying until you get a file that hasn't existed yet
    i+=1
    try:
        with open('output{}.txt'.format(i), 'x'): #this will fail if the file already exists
            #do something
        break
    except PermissionError:
        continue
```

This script will check if the first file, `output1.txt` already exists, and if it does, it will check if `output2.txt` exists, and so on, until it finds a file which hasn't exist just yet.

Hope this helps! :)